# Laplace transform of sinc function

Tags: fourier-analysis, laplace-transform

I want to solve the Laplace transform of

$$\frac{\sin(4(t-1))}{\pi(t-1)}  $$

I know that Fourier transform of a `sinc` funcion is `rect` function. However I found Laplace transform as  $\cot^{-1}(s)$. What is the reason of this difference?
**My Solution**
[image]

Secondly, How can I use the Laplace transform properties to solve this question?

Comment: $\mathcal{F}[f(t)](\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-i\omega t }dt$ and $\mathcal{F}[f(t)1_{t > 0}](\omega)=\int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-i\omega t }dt$ are **not** the same thing.

Comment: @reuns, do you mean the jump for $t=0$ or the integral limit?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:**

Let $F(s)$ be the Laplace Transform of $f(t)=\frac{\sin(t)}{t}u(t)$ where $u(t)$ is the unit step function (Heaviside Function).  Then, we have that

$$F(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(t)}{t}e^{-st}\,dt \tag1$$

Differentiating $(1)$ yields

$$F'(s)=-\int_0^\infty \sin(t)e^{-st}\,dt=-\frac1{s^2+1}\tag 2$$

Use $F(0)=\pi/2$ along with Laplace Transform relationships for time shifting and scaling.

Can you finish now?

---

**SPOLIER ALERT:  Scroll over the highlighted area to reveal a solution**

> Integrating $(2)$ and applying $F(0)=\pi/2$ reveals $$F(s)=\pi/2-\arctan(s)=\text{arccot}(s)$$Next, we exploit the Laplace Transform relationship $$\mathscr{L}\{f(b(t-a))\}(s)=\frac1b e^{as}\mathscr{L}\{f(t)\}(s/b)$$to write$$\begin{align}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(4(t-1))}{\pi (t-1)}u(t-1)e^{-st}\,dt&=\frac{4}{\pi}\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(4(t-1))}{4(t-1)}u(4(t-1))e^{-st}\,dt\\\\&=\frac1\pi e^{-s} \text{arccot}(s/4)\,dt\end{align}$$

Comment: Thanks   I  can do it .

Comment: You're welcome! My pleasure.

Comment: $\int_0^\infty \text{sinc}(t)e^{-st}\,dt$ and $\int_0^\infty \text{sinc}(at+b)e^{-st}\,dt$ are quite different

Comment: In which way? region of convergence or time shifting and scaling  ?@reuns

Comment: @distortion I presumed that $f(t)=\frac{\sin(4(t-1))}{\pi(t-1)}u(t-1)$.

Comment: Actually İt is impulse response h(t) and there is no such information @MarkViola

Comment: I took my answer and thanks for all your efforts @MarkViola

Comment: You're quite welcome.